# How to not get data if a field is found more than once

Tags: sql, cds

I'm getting results from a Query of installations and equipment number,
however if I have more than one equipment in an installation I want to omit that data.

```
select a~anlage, c~equnr
from eastl as a 
inner join egerh as b on a~logiknr = b~logiknr and a~bis = '99991231' and b~bis = '99991231'
inner join equi as c on b~equnr = c~equnr and c~matnr = 'REGULATOR'
group by a~anlage, c~equnr 
having count(*) = 1
```

---

My current results looks like this:

```
anlage - equnr
111111 - 01012
111111 - 01013
111111 - 01014
222222 - 01015
222222 - 01016
444444 - 01017
```

---

And I expect this:

```
anlage - equnr
444444 - 01017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to group by `a~anlage` only:

```
select a~anlage, max(c~equnr)
from eastl as a 
inner join egerh as b on a~logiknr = b~logiknr and a~bis = '99991231' and b~bis = '99991231'
inner join equi as c on b~equnr = c~equnr and c~matnr = 'REGULATOR'
group by a~anlage
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: It works! but I don't understand why could you please explain? with the code you provide i would assume my result would be: 111111 - 01014, 222222 - 01016 and 444444 - 01017 but its only 444444 - 01017.

Comment: You don't want the `anlage`s for which exist more than 1 equnr. This is why you should group by anlage only.

Comment: Thank you so much!